# Why my function doesn't return a value?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
duration=input("Enter day duration here:")
amount=input("Enter the amount here:")

def make_decision(duration,amount):

    if (duration<=0 or amount <=0):
        print "Invalid value"
    elif (duration<30):
        if (amount>=50):
            corresponding_value = "Medium"

        elif (amount<50):
            corresponding_value = "Low"

    elif (duration>=30):
        if (amount>=50):
            corresponding_value = "High"
        elif (amount<50):
            corresponding_value = "High"

    return corresponding_value

make_decision(duration,amount)
```

I don't understand why please help!When I run this, it just ends after getting inputs.
I fixed not accounted interval but it is still the same!

Comment: Maybe you wanna `print make_decision(duration,amount)`?

Comment: The `if` inside the `else` has the same outcome in both cases, and would thus appear superfluous. (Also its `elif` condition is necessarily true, so would be better as just `else`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is returning value alright but what you have missed is that when you are returning a value from a function either you have to collect that value in some variable and use it accordingly or you can just print it using print statement just before the function calling.

The updated code will be as:

```
duration=input("Enter day duration here:")
amount=input("Enter the amount here:")

def make_decision(duration,amount):

    if (duration<=0 or amount <=0):
        print "Invalid value"
    elif (duration<30):
        if (amount>=50):
            corresponding_value = "Medium"

        elif (amount<50):
            corresponding_value = "Low"

    elif (duration>=30):
        if (amount>=50):
            corresponding_value = "High"
        elif (amount<50):
            corresponding_value = "High"

    return corresponding_value

# this is one option
print make_decision(duration,amount)
# another option could be
# result = make_decision(duration, amount)
# print result
```

Answer (score 1):

As Tarun described, Your function is returning a value but not printing. Either  use

```
print corresponding_value
```

instead of return. So when you call the function by using

```
make_decision(duration,amount)
```

you will get the output printed in the console.

Another way of doing it is

```
print make_decision(duration,amount)
```

And there are other ways also.

Also, in the second part of your function

```
if (amount>=50):
        corresponding_value = "High"
 elif (amount<50):
        corresponding_value = "High"
```

Probably, there is some typo error. As both case prints the same text. If you need same text 'High' to be printed for duration >= 30 and amount > 0, then  elif condition is not required. Better way of writing is:

```
def make_decision(duration,amount):

if (duration<=0 or amount <=0):
    print "Invalid value"
elif (duration<30):
    if (amount>=50):
        corresponding_value = "Medium"

    elif (amount<50):
        corresponding_value = "Low"
else:
        corresponding_value = "High"
print corresponding_value
```

make_decision(duration,amount)